# Jasper Report Font Extension SansSerif Font Name

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I made a font extension of Arial but named it as SansSerif so that my previous reports which uses font name SansSerif would not need any modification. I know that SansSerif is a logical font name and not a physical one. I added the font extension to my project's web library. If deployed on a server, would the server look for the SansSerif as the font Arial I made in the font extension, or would it treat the font name SansSerif as a logical font and use whatever default font is present in the JVM machine?

Thank you.